# Is it safe to change a CALayer's attributes from a background thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, calayer

I want to do an animation that is responsive to device motion and I'd like it to remain smooth even if the UI thread is momentarily busy. The animation consists of changing a CALayer's bezier path. I've tried doing it from a secondary thread but I get occasional hangs where the main thread has a trashed stack. Is what I'm doing totally hopeless? Here's what I do in the thread:

```
[CATransaction lock];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                 forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
[CATransaction begin];
myLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:theRect].CGPath;
myLayer.bounds = theBounds;
[CATransaction commit];

[CATransaction flush];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanFalse
                 forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
[CATransaction unlock];
```

Comment: While you should be fine to update layers from a secondary thread, I noticed a relevant detail in the Core Animation Programming Guide: "Shape layers ... do involve rendering the shape on the main thread and caching the results." Doesn't explain the crash but it may explain the hangs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

updating the ui from any thread except the uithread is prohibited
so you will have to do the following:

```
- (void) updateUI
{
[CATransaction lock];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                 forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
[CATransaction begin];
myLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:theRect].CGPath;
myLayer.bounds = theBounds;
[CATransaction commit];

[CATransaction flush];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanFalse
                 forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
[CATransaction unlock];
}
```

and from the other thread

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: Are the Core Animation locks really necessary? Also, why would you use performSelectorOnMainThread instead of using the main dispatch queue?

Comment: The locks was from the original code, but yes i guess they may be unnecessary, about the performSelectorOnMainThread i added it for simplicity, please feel free to edit :)

Comment: Well, my answer would use dispatch queues and do away with the CA stuff. I'll just post it separately for reference.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my version.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            myLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:theRect].CGPath;
            myLayer.bounds = theBounds;
        });
```

Dispatch queues give you the advantage of being able to pull in variables from the local scope without having to worry about implementing intermediate data structures.

Comment: Your dispatch queue is running on the main queue, so it's not in a background thread, so not really relevant to the question. Though fair enough if you put it on a background queue.

Comment: The question was about changing a CALayer's attribute from a background thread. This is not possible, but the next best implementation is to queue a change on the main thread. So in that sense I thought it would be helpful to include this code snippet because what the question presupposes is otherwise impossible.

Comment: Ah for some reason I thought the accepted answer was calling performSelectorInBackground. Never mind then, this is fine and cleaner than using a performSelector call.